# I get some errors while try to install mongodb

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I'm new in ubuntu and mongodb both.ubuntu is installed on vm hosted windows 8.1.I tried to install **mongodb v4.2.2** on **ubuntu v18.04 bionic**:

---

Importing the public key

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.2.asc | sudo apt-key add -
OK
```

---

Install gnupg and its required libraries

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install gnupg
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gnupg is already the newest version (2.2.4-1ubuntu1.2).
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  linux-modules-5.0.0-36-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 55 not upgraded.
```

---

Retry importing the key

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.2.asc | sudo apt-key add -
OK
```

---

Create the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.2.list file for Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic)

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ echo "deb [ arch=amd64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.2 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.2.list
deb [ arch=amd64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.2 multiverse
```

---

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease              
Hit:3 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease              
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]   
Hit:6 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_13.x bionic InRelease                    
Ign:7 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.0 InRelease     
Ign:8 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.2 InRelease     
Hit:9 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.0 Release       
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]
Hit:11 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.2 Release      
Get:4 http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist InRelease [121 kB]
Err:4 http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Reading package lists... Done 
E: Failed to fetch http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart/dists/dist/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: The repository 'http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

As you can see I get some errors on this step which I could not fix.
As a matter of fact I have no idea what the cause of errors.

---

I installed mongodb with no errors anyway

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

---

Then I started it and checked its status

```
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-01-21 10:24:32 PST; 4s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 2164 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=48)
 Main PID: 2164 (code=exited, status=48)

Jan 21 10:24:32 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Jan 21 10:24:32 ubuntu systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=48/n/a
Jan 21 10:24:32 ubuntu systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

please help me fix this problem

Answer (score 2):

```
systemctl stop mongod.service
systemctl disable mongod.service
sudo apt remove --autoremove mongodb-org
```

Remove mongodb repo list

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb*.list
```

update the changes

```
sudo apt update
```

Add mongodb Key

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv B00A0BD1E2C63C11
```

Add new repository

```
echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc)/mongodb-org/5.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org.list
```

Update the key and repo

```
sudo apt update
```

Install MongoDB

```
sudo apt install mongodb-org
```

check the status

```
systemctl status mongod.service
```

Comment: This worked for me, especially after trying a few other methods and having bad mongo versions on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt remove --autoremove mongodb-org
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb*.list
sudo apt update
```

Then Just reboot the server

the above commands will uninstall all mongodb related files and this will correct any package has error, and try to reinstall again it will work

Comment: Although this might provide a solution, please elaborate on what these commands will do.